# keyboard event is not appending the text in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to append text to the paragraph tag when a user types something in the input box but I can't get it to work.

```
<head>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("saurabh").keypress(function(){
            $("p").append("text");
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    Enter your name: <input type="text" id="saurabh">

    <p id="p"> </p>
</body>
```

Comment: When selecting an element by `id`, you need to precede the `id` with a `#`. Change `$("saurabh")` to `$("#saurabh")`.

Comment: You have completely changed the code in the question so my previous comment and @cpburnx's answer no longer make any sense. You shouldn't do that. If you still have an issue after your making the suggested changes, you should either append to your question, ask another question, or ask a short follow-up question in a comment.

Comment: With the new code, you should use `$("#message")` instead of `$("#input")`.

Comment: @JohnS   thnx john .......

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues with your code.

1. To reference `<input type="text" id="saurabh">`, you need to use `$('#saurabh')` not `$('saurabh')`.
2. To reference `<p id="p">`, you should really use `$('#p')` instead of `$('p')` so that every `<p>` on the page doesn't receive the text.
3. In order to get the text inputted into `$('#saurabh')` from its callback, use `$(this).val()` instead of `"text"`.
4. Even though you are trying to append the text to `$('#p')` with `$('#p').append(...)`, I think you really are looking for `$('#p').text(...)` to set the text of `#p` after every key-press.

You want to change:

```
$("saurabh").keypress(function(){
    $("p").append("text");
});
```

To:

```
$("#saurabh").keypress(function(){
    $("#p").text($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: NIice and thorough answer to what was the original question.